# Objective PHP and key value coding

Tags: php, key-value-coding

In some part of my code I need something like this:

```
$product_type = $product->type;
$price_field = 'field_'.$product_type.'_price';
$price = $product->$$price_field;
```

In other words I need kind of KVC - means get object field by field name produced at the runtime.
I simply need to extend some existing system and keep field naming convention so do not advice me to change field names instead.

I know something like this works for arrays, when you could easily do that by:

```
$price = $product[$price_field_key].
```

So I can produce key for array dynamically.
But how to do that for objects?
Please help me as google gives me river of results for arrays, etc...
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$price = $product->{$price_field};
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry Guys.
It was much easier than I thought.
Hopefullty it will help someone. Simply put:

```
$price_field = 'field_'.$product_type.'_price';
$price = $product->$price_field;
```

So you can use varialbe to get object field in Php.

I went to far with those $$ ;-)

Regards

Comment: FYI, using $$ resolves the contents of the variable. e.g., `$a = 'b'; $b = 'key'; echo $foo->$$a` is the same as `$foo->key` in this example.

Answer (score 1):

How about using [get_object_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)?

```
$price_field = 'field_'.$product_type.'_price';
$instvars = get_object_vars($product);
$price = $instvars[$price_field];
```

Comment: actualy this looks more like a hack ;-) but i like it +1

Answer (score 1):

Actualy it would work as follows.

```
$product_type = $product->type;


$price_field = "field_".$product_type"._price";


$price = $product->$price_field;
```